# How to fix 1/59=0.016949153 without 1/59=0 in bash script

Tags: bash, output

In bash script, I have 1 script like this:

```
n1 = 1
n0 = 59

# compute p1
p1=$((n1/n0))
echo "p1 = $p1"
```

I'd like my output is p1 = 1/59 = 0.016949153
but reality, output is p1 = 0

So, How to fix it. help me please

Comment: [tag:bash] cannot handle floats. You could multiply it by e.g. 1000 if you want a precision of 3 decimals and then print it accordingly. Better to use [tag:awk] though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BASH doesn't do any floating point maths. You can either use `bc` or `awk` for that.

For ex::

```
p1=$(bc -l <<< "scale=5; $n1/$n0")
echo "$p1"
.01694
```

**UPDATE:** Using awk:

```
awk -v n1=$n1 -v n0=$n0 'BEGIN{printf("%.5f\n", (n1/n0))}'
0.01695
```

Comment: if i want my output to change from .01694915254237288135 to .01695. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: @TrungTrung: See update on using `scale=5`

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just solved this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bc` to get arbitrary precision maths:

```
pax> n1=355 ; n0=113
pax> p1=$(echo "scale=50;$n1/$n0" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999 bc) ; echo $p1
3.14159292035398230088495575221238938053097345132743
```

The line length stops `bc` from doing its annoying line break behaviour for longer results.

If you have a more reverse polish mindset like me, you can also use `dc`:

```
pax> n1=355 ; n0=113
pax> echo 50 k $n1 $n0 / p | dc
3.14159292035398230088495575221238938053097345132743
```

In both cases, you can set the scale to be used (by setting `scale` in `bc` or using the `k` command in `dc`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add

```
p1=$(python -c "print $n1*1.0/$n0")
```